# How to suppress "Failed to set controlling terminal" warning in GDB when setting program to run on another terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, tty, gdb, pty

I'm using GDB to debug a program, and I want to direct its output to a different terminal than the one where GDB is running. Here's what I've been doing:

1. Open a second terminal, check its device name using `tty`, and get something like `/dev/pts/14`.
2. In my GDB session, I use the command `tty /dev/pts/14` to set the output to that terminal.
3. Then I issue the `run` command in GDB to start the program.

This setup does correctly direct the output to terminal 2, but the problem is that the first line on terminal 2 always says:

```
warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted
```

I tried running GDB as root using `sudo` but encountered the same warning. Here's a simplified representation of my process:

```bash
# Terminal 2:
$ tty
/dev/pts/14

# Terminal 1:
$ gdb ./some-program
(gdb) tty /dev/pts/14
(gdb) run
```

Would anyone be able to explain what's causing this warning and how I could resolve or suppress it? What does GDB attempt to do when setting the controlling terminal, and why is it failing?

**Note:** Same things happens on a classic tty like `/dev/tty3`